# mySQL cant see the table created

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new to SQL and I downloaded the SQL workbench.
I typed some commands to create a table, but where can I see the table?

Comment: You can see the table in the schema you created it in. We have no way of knowing what database you were connected to, nor what schema you were in when you created your table, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for your patient suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see a schema section where you'll see a databases. Expand the database where you created the table, you should see the table you've created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I still did not see. By saying "table" I mean the physical table consisting of squares of data. Will it appear somewhere?

Comment: You have to write a query to select data to see it output it's data. MySQL Workbench is a different animal than MS SQL Server Manager or Toad, for example.